# When are two level sets of a function diffeomorphic?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be a polynomial over $n$ variables. Let $m(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be a monomial in the same variables.

Are the surfaces $\{f=x_{n+1}\}$ and $\{f+m=x_{n+1}\}$ diffeomorphic?

My thought is that since we can easily deform one to the other by defining $f_s=f+s\, m$ with $s\in[0,1]$ and since there is not singularity to appear they have to be diffeomorphic. Is this true? If not, what can go wrong? If yes, is it a proof?

Comment: Do you know the definition of diffeomorphic? Generally the property that two things "deform" to each other is either a strictly stronger or strictly weaker notion than diffeomorphic. Anyway two graphs of smooth functions $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ are always diffeomorphic as the map $\Bbb R^n \to \Gamma_f\subset \Bbb R^{n+1}$, $x \mapsto (x,f(x))$ is easily seen to be a diffeomorphism once one knows the proper definitions.

Comment: With no conditions on $f$? What if $f=0$? What if $f=-m$?

Comment: @PVAL-inactive What you're saying is true but irrelevant for this post, which concerns 0 level sets rather than graphs.

Comment: Think about the simple case $m=1$ - it's quite possible that the topology of the level sets differ. This happens when $f$ has critical values between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: In @PVAL's defense, note that the title refers to *graphs*. rom, it would be best if you phrased the title correctly and said something like "When are level sets of different functions diffeomorphic?"

Comment: OMG, it is completely trivial. I realized that I don't know exactly what my problem is. I need to clarify this bit first. Also sorry for the confusion. I said graphs and I wrote level sets. I actually meant graphs. I was late...

Comment: Well, you meant graphs, so then you should not change the title!! It should be changed back. See how confusing things are with the inconsistency?

Comment: I didn't change the title

Answer (score 0):

Your argument does not work in general. See Mohan's comment for example. However, it does work if the following two conditions are satisfied:

i) The point $0\in\mathbb{R}$ is a regular value of $f_s=f+sm$ for every $s\in[0,1]$.

ii) The fiber $f_s^{-1}(0)$ (which is smooth, as follows from condition i)) is compact for every $s\in[0,1]$.

To see this, we shall use the following **Fact:** If $\pi:M\to N$ is a submersion between two smooth manifolds, and if the fiber $\pi^{-1}(n)$ is compact for every $n\in N$, then all the fibers are diffeomorphic to one another.

We now prove that under the above conditions, all the sets $f_s^{-1}(0)$ are diffeomorphic to one another. Define $$M=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n,s)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,1]|f_s(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0\}.$$As $0$ is a regular value of $f_s$ for every $s$, it is surely a regular value of $$\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,1],\quad(x_1,\ldots,x_n,s)\mapsto f_s(x_1,\ldots,x_n).$$Consequently, $M$ is a smooth manifold (with boundary at $s=0,1$). Furthermore, at every $p\in M$ we have $$T_pM=\ker d\phi_p\not\subset T_p\mathbb{R}^n$$(keeping in mind the decomposition $T_pM=T_p\mathbb{R}^n\oplus T_p[0,1]$). This means that the projection$$\pi:M\to[0,1],\quad(x_1,\ldots,x_n,s)\mapsto s$$is a submersion. Its fibers are compact by condition ii) and hence diffeomorphic to one another by the quoted fact.